# How to store an object data as secret value

Tags: azure-keyvault

I need to store two strings as one secret value in key vault.
account="aa" key="1254"

But all SetSecretAsync syntaxes accept one string as secret value..

I am not sure if tags can be revelevant here.

Please help!

Comment: Do you mean SetSecretAsync("aSecretIdentifier","account=""aa"" key=""1254""")?

Comment: Something like that but i would rather to have two separated string or having an object with two string values. I couldn't find a solution to have an object as a secret value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Newtonsoft Json.NET to serialize an object to a JSON string:

```
var account = new Account { account = "aa", key = "1254" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account);
```

This string will contain this:

```
{"account":"aa","key":"1254"}
```

which can be stored as the secret.

When you subsequently load the secret, you could then use Json.NET to deserialize the string back into an object:

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

As for tags, you could use a tag to indicate what's contained within the secret, and this could be useful if you'll be storing different object types within secrets (not just accounts, for instance). Tags are just key-value pairs, so you could create a tag like so:

```
secret.Tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["Type"] = "Account"
};
```

But if you're always going to be storing accounts, then this isn't strictly necessary.